# convert "days hh:mm:ss" field to hh:mm:ss or seconds using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I want to take the following tab delimited input and revise the days in the time duration in fields 4 and 5 to an Excel friendly time duration, either HH:MM:SS or ideally seconds. These fields measure uptime that may span 00:00:00 to hundreds of days.
Input:

```
<ip-address>  field(2 / 2)  field:(3:3)   2 days 18:18:27  23:23:57          n kB   n GB
<ip-address>  field(2 / 2)  field:(3:3)   18:18:27         23:23:57          n kB   n GB
<ip-address>  field(2 / 2)  field:(3:3)   18:18:27         2 days 23:23:57   n kB   n GB
<ip-address>  field(2 / 2)  field:(3:3)   2 days 18:18:27  21 days 23:23:57  n kB   n GB
```

Desired output for first record, either of:

```
<ip-address>  field(2 / 2)  field:(3:3)   66:18:27         23:23:57          n kB   n GB
<ip-address>  field(2 / 2)  field:(3:3)   2387027          84237             n kB   n GB
```

When the file is tab delimited there are seven fields; if delimited using tab, space and : it's more like 30. Fields 2 and 3 are longer but about the same complexity as shown.

Using sed I can create an expression but do not know how to evaluate it in place:

```
sed "s/\([0-9]\+\) days \([0-9]\+\)/\1*24+\2/g" file
<ip-address>    field(2 / 2)    field:(3:3)    2*24+18:18:27      23:23:57    n kB   n GB
```

I know sed has an evaluate method but it passes the entire pattern space back to the shell

```
sed "s/\([0-9]\+\) days \([0-9]\+\)/\1*24+\2/e" file
<ip-address> is not recognised as an internal or external command yada yada
```

I know how to use fields in an awk expression `hrs = $2 * 24 + $3`, but in this case the field needs to be split first. Splitting the line into 30 fields seems not worth doing.

Is there a way to split a field in awk and then evaluate an expression on the components, or evaluate the expression above in sed, or otherwise?

Using Gnu sed and awk on Win7. Currently no bc, would prefer to avoid unless it's compelling.

Edit: Clarified days is optional in either field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} 
           {split($4,d," days "); 
            split(d[2],t,":"); 
            h=d[1]*24+t[1]; 
            $4=h":"t[2]":"t[3]; 
            print; 
            $4=(h*60+t[2])*60+t[3]}1' file

<ip-address>    field(2 / 2)    field:(3:3) 66:18:27    23:23:57    n kB    n GB
<ip-address>    field(2 / 2)    field:(3:3) 238707  23:23:57    n kB    n GB
```

Comment: Great. I've edited my original post to clarify that days may be present in either field and only need one output row. I discovered (so don't need to ask) that the trailing 1 causes the second print so easy to modify. What is the best way to handle both $4 and $5 this way, and handle the absence of `" days "` in either field? I'm thinking `awk 'BEGIN {} / days / in $4* {split($4...} / days / in $5* {split{$5...}'` (* somehow...)

Comment: perhaps creating a function is better in this case of two fields needing the same treatment...

Comment: My current solution is: `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} $4~/ day[s]? / {split($4,d," day[s]? "); split(d[2],t,":"); h=d[1]*24+t[1]; $4=h":"t[2]":"t[3]} $5~/ day[s]? / {split($5...}1' file` - turns out uptime of a day results in 1 day xx:xx:xx. The regex complicates conversion to seconds. Pondering a function. Windows `\"` escapes omitted for clarity inside the script. Thanks!